# How to test a FHE implementation?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, ntru

I want to implement a FHE scheme based on NTRU, namely the scheme described here https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/039.pdf . How to test the security of my implementation ? Do I have to implement the attacks against NTRU-FHE by myself or there are already some programs that do this?

Comment: Take a look at the paper [Which Ring Based Somewhat Homomorphic Encryption Scheme is Best?](http://ia.cr/2015/889) by Ana Costache and Nigel Smart. They show how to derive secure parameters for four different FHE schemes, two of them being based on NTRU. For the security of the underlying LWE problem you can use the [online LWE security estimation tool](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/LWESecurity/) by Lauren De Meyer.