# What is the bound for the probability distribution for ATV-FHE scheme?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, ntru

I try to implement the ATV-FHE scheme as described in this paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/039.pdf.

How do I choose the bound for the probability distribution chi?

How do I choose standard deviation for this distribution?

Comment: As I already commented to [another question from you](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30160/how-to-test-a-fhe-implementation), the easiest way to obtain parameters for ATV=LTV is [Which Ring Based Somewhat Homomorphic Encryption Scheme is Best?](http://ia.cr/2015/889) by Ana Costache and Nigel Smart. They call the scheme NTRU.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was trying to take the low road and find quickly what I want. But I guess I have no choice and I'll read the paper ;).

Comment: The last third of the paper (Appendix E.6) are just tables describing the parameters for various number of levels and plaintext moduli. No need to read the rest if you travel "on the low road".